# how to make 3 items align with the first to the left, second to the right top and third right bottom?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following html.
`<div><item1><item2><item3><div>`. The items are `div`s. I would like the items to be displayed in two columns. The item2 to be in the left column by itself. In the right column, item1 to align to the top and item3 to be aligned to the bottom.
Here is the layout [image]

How can I do this with flexbox or float?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean by `<item1><item2><item3>` if it's text you could use `text-align` if it's something like `div` element or image use `float`

Comment: If you want both columns to be dynamic/sized by their content, no, with fixed height on the `div`, yes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments. I have clarified the question. @Simon, if I float the item2 to the left and float item1 and item3 to the right, then the item1 and item3 will be on the right but the will not be in the same column right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce the desired effect.

You need to use `float: right;` to put the `div` to the right.
and `float: left;` to position the div to the left.

```css
#main {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#first {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}

#second {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>
    item1
  </h1>
</div>

<div id="first">
  <h1>
    item2
  </h1>
</div>

<div id="second">
  <h1>
    item3
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. nice trick with the `width:50%` on the two right floated divs. That made them stack up. Cheers!

Comment: @edster No problem, happy to help. : )

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with flexbox and float, but I would probably use css-grid for that.

That way you can even keep your current order.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;  /*you can use px, %, auto etc. here*/
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "left-item right-top" "left-item right-bottom";
  
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: left-item;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: right-top;
  
  background-color: red;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: right-bottom;
  
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```

I would however consider making a (mobile) version without css-grid as a fallback, but as your layout is right now, I assume it is meant for desktop/tablet anyways?

Comment: That's impressive.  Do you know where I can find good documentation for that?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ Is pretty good. There really isn't much to it. Try doing it a few times and you will soon learn to use it automatically. And it is really useful (took me about 2 min. writing that layout, without much thinking) Note, however, that it is still rather new.

Comment: Is it supported in all browsers?

Comment: In the modern ones, kinda. I don't want to go into detail as it was some time ago that I last checked, but then it was like this: Chrome and Firefox work as intended. IE10 and Edge use the original standard that isn't used anymore (affects inline-gid), but are planning on adapting the new one. Like I said in my post, try making a version without first. That version will probably be mobile. If grid isn't supported then your website will still look "as good as possible" on that browser. (usually it works better than most people expect)

Comment: IE always causes problems.  Thanks for that last comment

Comment: Well in this case you can actually thank IE for it, as IE and Edge were the ones creating it (as far as I am aware). It's just that the online community decided that they wanted to change the way nested grids work.

Comment: This is very nice answer too @SourceOverflow. I did pick the solution using float. However, this is definitely the way of the future!

Comment: @edster Yeah, it probably is and that's why I posted it. I realise that you asked for float, but anyone else seeing this question should be aware of the possibility of css-grid

Comment: @SourceOverflow Don't use single comments `//` in CSS, they will break it, use `/* */`

Comment: @LGSon really? I never had any problems with it. But I will trust you and edit my answer

Comment: @SourceOverflow Stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. You can make a table having two columns. In the second column, you can make two rows. Finally put your item in the table.

Here that I made:

```css
 table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>item1</th>
        <th>
        <table>
            <tr>item2</tr>
            <br><br>
            <tr>item3</tr>
        </table>
        </th>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: It's good don't get me wrong but tables are supposedly for text not `div` elements.  Yes it works but many would consider it bad practice.  I called it a cheat because it is not a recommended way to do it but it works anyway

Answer (score -1):

use position relative for your div and position absolute for your items with  a 0 value for top left right or bottom attribute